# Picture cropped when using display.save to store a photo with Corona SDK

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I'm working on a small project to take pictures with Android devices, and then sending these files to a web server. The pictures are being taken without problems, but the "display.save" section is cropping the file to the size of the screen.

```
local function FotoTomada(event)
  if (event.completed == true) then
    display.save( event.target, "foto.jpg", {isFullResolution=true})
    SubirFoto()
  end
end
```

If my cell phone has a screen resolution of 480x500, that's the resolution the picture saved to a file is getting. Does anyone know of any workaround for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you tell us the `event.target` size? Bigger than device's resolution?

Comment: Hi Albert. Yes, the target.size is bigger than the device's resolution. The event.target is a picture taken with the device's camera. Thanks!

Comment: In Corona doc it says **event.target is a DisplayObject based on the mediaSource parameter**  so could you print the `event.target.contentWidth` & `event.target.contentHeight` when `event.complete==true`? BY THE WAY  you can provid the destination in `media.capturePhoto( { listener, [, destination] } )` see [CoronaDocs](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/media/capturePhoto.html)

Comment: Using media.capturePhoto with the "destination" parameter solved it. Please post it as an answer to give you credit for it. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provid the destination in media.capturePhoto( { listener, [, destination] } ) see [CoronaDocs](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/media/capturePhoto.html)

Comment: If I give it the destination parameter it still saves it to the default photo library and the default filenaming system, so it is disregarding TempDirectory and Filename that I give it, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, that only saves the photo in your device resolution. Use this directly to save it to wherever you want:

local function onComplete( event )
   local photo = event.target
   print( "photo w,h = " .. photo.width .. "," .. photo.height )
end

if media.hasSource( media.Camera ) then
    media.capturePhoto( { listener=onComplete } )
else
    native.showAlert( "Corona", "This device does not have a camera.", { "OK" } )
end